# Type annotations required when using BTreeSet::range on a set of &str

Tags: rust, set, range, binary-tree, type-inference

I faceed some trouble using the `BTreeSet::range` method.

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeSet;
use std::ops::Bound::Included;

fn main() {
    let set = BTreeSet::new();

    set.insert("TEST1");
    set.insert("TEST3");
    set.insert("TEST4");
    set.insert("TEST2");
    set.insert("TEST5");

    let bound = (Included("TEST3"), Included("TEST4"));
    let rg = set.range(bound);

    println!("result: {:?}", rg);
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_: std::cmp::Ord`
  --> src/main.rs:14:18
   |
14 |     let rg = set.range(bound);
   |                  ^^^^^
```

Does that means that `&str` cannot be compared to each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler cannot infer the first generic parameter (`K: Ord`) of the `range` function from an `Included` argument.

You need to specify it explicitly:

```rust
let rg = set.range::<&str, _>(bound);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1fce8b475a81792d11b5453c8c0bc8df)

## Why can the compiler not infer the first generic parameter?

It actually does infers the type, but there are 2 candidate types for `K`: it can be `&'static str` or `str`. Rust cannot be sure which one to use.

Let's analyze the definition of the `range` method to explain why Rust cannot select one of them.

```rust
pub fn range<K: ?Sized, R>(&self, range: R) -> Range<'_, T>
where
    K: Ord,
    T: Borrow<K>,
    R: RangeBounds<K>,
```

`K` is a dynamically sized type, `T` can be represented as `K` and `R` is an input which should implement `RangeBounds<K>`.

`RangeBounds<T>` has 2 different implementation for Tuple Range:

```rust
// first
impl<'a, T: ?Sized + 'a> RangeBounds<T> for (Bound<&'a T>, Bound<&'a T>){}
```

In the *first* implementation, `str` satisfies `T`; it is unsized and lives in the `'static` lifetime. If `K` is a `str`, then you can have an argument like: `(Inbound("val1"), Inbound("val2"))`

```rust
// second
impl<T> RangeBounds<T> for (Bound<T>, Bound<T>){}
```

In the *second* implementation, `&str` satisfies `T`. If `K` is a `&str` then you can have an argument like `(Inbound("val1"), Inbound("val2"))`

As you can see, both types of arguments are identical, and Rust has two options for `K`. As a result, it cannot select one of them because both options fit and it expects you to define it explicitly.

```rust
let rg = set.range::<str, _>(bound);
```

This will also work and the compiler will use the *first* implementation. Since both implementations do the same thing, the results will be identical.

**See also:**

- [1st implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops/range.rs.html#827)
- [2nd implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops/range.rs.html#808)

Answer (score 3):

A range is constructed via the `..` (exclusive end) or `..=` (inclusive end) operators, e.g. `for i in 0..3` means `0, 1, 2`. In contrast `for i in 0..=3` means `0, 1, 2, 3`.

To solve your problem, you can specify an inclusive range:

```
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

fn main() {
    let mut set = BTreeSet::new();

    set.insert("TEST1");
    set.insert("TEST3");
    set.insert("TEST4");
    set.insert("TEST2");
    set.insert("TEST5");

    let rg = set.range("TEST3"..="TEST4");

    println!("result: {:?}", rg);
}
```

which will print

```
result: Range { iter: [("TEST3", ()), ("TEST4", ())] }
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.RangeBounds.html#impl-RangeBounds%3CT%3E-5

Comment: Why can it infer the type for `RangeInclusive` but not for a tuple of `Bound`?

Comment: @hellow Thanks for the alternate syntax. I've a lot to discover!